# How to pass Error Details and line number from QuickFix while developing an extension in VSCode?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am trying to develop a plugin, where it shows issues related to a particular  line.

I am  able to implement `Quick Fix`.
Here it parses the issues and displays it :

```
const uri = vscode.Uri.file(path);
const doc = await vscode.workspace.openTextDocument(uri);
//fix ranges to not include whitespace
issues.forEach((issue) => {

  codeActions.push({
    title: "Uppercase the keyword",
    kind: CodeActionKind.QuickFix,
    diagnostics: [issue]
  });

  const line = doc.lineAt(issue.range.start.line);
  issue.range = new vscode.Range(
    new vscode.Position(line.range.start.line, line.firstNonWhitespaceCharacterIndex),
    line.range.end
  );
});

collection.set(uri, issues);
```

CodeActionProvider missing :

```
import * as vscode from 'vscode';

export class ApexCodeActionProvider implements vscode.CodeActionProvider {

    public provideCodeActions(
        document: vscode.TextDocument,
        _range: vscode.Range,
        _context: vscode.CodeActionContext,
        _token: vscode.CancellationToken
    ): vscode.ProviderResult<vscode.CodeAction[]> {
        const autoFixQuickFix = new vscode.CodeAction('AutoFix QuickFix', vscode.CodeActionKind.QuickFix);
        autoFixQuickFix.command = {
            title: 'AutoFix QuickFix',
            command: 'apex-pmd.fixFile'
        };

        return [autoFixQuickFix];
    }

}
```

Register this in extension.ts

```
context.subscriptions.push(
    vscode.languages.registerCodeActionsProvider(supportedLanguageCodes, new ApexCodeActionProvider(), {
        providedCodeActionKinds: [vscode.CodeActionKind.QuickFix]
    })
);
```

But I am not able to pass the error details and the line number? Any idea how to pass that? And how to edit or change the text from text editor?

Comment: a CodeAction **must** have an `edit` or a `command`

Comment: Yes I know that, I read the docs also saying `A CodeAction must set either edit and/or a command. If both are supplied, the edit is applied first, then the command is executed.`, but even after putting that, how to attach those quick fix on editor? Any example?

Comment: show your minimal complete extension with CodeAction, or search the examples to find one. Do you have a `CodeActionProvider`?

Comment: No I dont have that.

Comment: Thanks for the direction @rioV8, I am able to display the QuickFix now, any idea how to pass error details and line number or Line on which quickFix is displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to supply a `vscode.CodeActionProvider`.

This `CodeActionProvider` when called returns a list of `vscode.CodeAction` objects.

In the `CodeAction` you set an `vscode.WorkspaceEdit` and/or a `vscode.Command`.

In the `WorkspaceEdit` you define the delete/insert/replace you want to QuickFix.

In the `Command` you can set an `arguments` property where you can put the command arguments. This array will be one of the parameters of the command.

Comment: Can we edit workspace after using command, and what to pass in `arguments : []`

`const autoFixQuickFix = new vscode.CodeAction('AutoFix QuickFix', vscode.CodeActionKind.QuickFix);
        autoFixQuickFix.command = {
            title: 'AutoFix QuickFix',
            command: 'apex-pmd.fixFile',
            arguments: []
        };`

Comment: @NagendraSingh It depends what `apex-pmd.fixFile` needs/does. Maybe you need to add a command to translate from the array of arguments to a comma separated list of arguments or just use `...args`.